# DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString) - Method threw 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException' exception

Tags: java, sql-server, database-connection, connection-string, mssql-jdbc

I am trying to connect to my database using JDBC driver. I have to use my another windows domain credential to connect and getting login failed error. Thought of testing it with my actual windows credential and it worked. I have used integratedSecurity = true.

```
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://server;databaseName=DB;integratedSecurity=true";
```

My desired connection string to use my another windows domain credential looks like the below:

```
 String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://server;databaseName=DB;user=domain\\user;password=test!123;"
```

I did the following things and in need of help:

1. Placed the sqljdbc_auth inside jdk/bin and jre/bin
2. SQL Server has been kept under the mixed auth mode (both Windows and SQL Auth).
3. Using my another domain ID, I tried to execute a query in MS SQL Studio and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [Microsoft JDBC driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server), you can:

- Connect with SQL Auth, using `user` and `password`
- Connect with Window Auth, using `integratedSecurity=true`, which will use the Windows user that is running the Java program
- Connect with Kerberos Auth, but that is complex to setup: [Using Kerberos Integrated Authentication to Connect to SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-kerberos-integrated-authentication-to-connect-to-sql-server)

If you want to do a simple NTLM connect using `domain`, `user` and `password`, then you need to use the [jTDS JDBC driver](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/).